# C++ equations, not sure if i wrote it correctly

Tags: c++

Are [image] and [image] correctly written?

```
if(x>0.1){z = 2*n+x}

if else(x <= 0.1){x(pow,n) - 1 / sqrt(n(pow,2)) + x(pow,2) * n}


 x = n / 2 * n(pow,2) + 3 * n - 2
```

Comment: What is `if else` that you write ?

Comment: Also what is the `x(pow,n)` function? It does all look completely wrong.

Comment: in the image u can see that x is powered by n

Comment: @Nenq _"x is powered by n"_ Well, `x(pow,n)` doesn't do this, you need to write `pow(x,n)`.

Comment: I think you should study c syntax.  @Nenq

Comment: Instead of trying to cram the entire `x <= 0.1` condition on 1 line, there is no shame in breaking it up into several lines.

Comment: Why does your formula have "square root of `n^2`" in the denominator when that value is simply just `n`?

Answer (score -2):

**x** is correctly translated to C++.

As for the rest of the code, it would be:

```
if(x > 0.1) {
    z = 2 * n + x;
}
else {
    z = pow(x, n) - 1 / sqrt(pow(n, 2) + pow(x, 2) * n);
}
```

Comment: _"As for the rest of the code, it would be..."_ Are you really sure about this??

Comment: x has to be > 0.1 and then x has to be <= 0.1

Comment: @Nenq, if x isn't > 0.1, it can only be <= 0.1